# How to set counter in nested while loop in jMeter?

Tags: jmeter

in my jmeter test I have a loop controller which works on messages got from previous thread group with a while loop inside. In while I'm sending GET as long as it is not successful. I would like to know how many of GETs was send. It looks like this:

```
-Loop Controller
--While (${__javaScript("${statusCode}"!="200")})
----Counter (on retry variable)
----GET ${retry}
```

I thought that every while loop will have an individual counter, but it's not. The counter gets incremented in every Loop Controller iteration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you need [__counter()](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) function instead of [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) Config Element. It's incremented by one on call, not on iteration.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T I am facing a similar problem where i have a while condition i.e. ${__javaScript(${Status_Code}<"11" && ${Status_Code}!="11",)} the status code should be greater than 11 and also max number of times the while loop should run is 20. How do i set the same?